# Keep height of auto height DIV when content gets hidden

Tags: html, height

I have a div with auto height and and image in it. When I click to get the image hidden, the div container should stay at its height. I know I could achieve this with a fixed height div, but because there are several divs / images with various heights, I can't do it that way.

https://jsfiddle.net/t6w3fkg8/

```
$(".content").click(function(){
"use strict";
$(this).hide();
```

});

Comment: can you share your code...

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/t6w3fkg8/

Comment: If you are satistief with one of the answers, please pick one answer to accept as the solution. This will help other user in the future to find a solution to their problem.

Answer (score 2):

`display:none` means that the tag in question will not appear on the page at all (although you can still interact with it through the dom).  There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags.

`visibility:hidden` means that unlike `display:none`, the tag is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page. The tag is rendered, it just isn't seen on the page.

You probably are using `display:none` at the moment. Try with `visibility:hidden`instead.

Edit: I updated your Fiddle with `visibility:hidden`: https://jsfiddle.net/xhmp8wj7/1/

Answer (score 0):

To the element, you can add a class with `visibility: hidden` when the `div` is clicked. Example:

```js
$(".content").click(function(){
    "use strict";
 $(this).addClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.container {
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #EFEFEF;
 padding: 10px;
 
}

.content {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color: #AAA;
}

.content.hidden {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
</div>
1234
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(".content").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('hide');
});
```

CSS

```
.content.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

> **Update**:

```
$(".content").click(function(){
    "use strict";
  var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
  $(this).parent().css({'height' : parentHeight+'px'});
    $(this).toggleClass("content-magnified");
});
```

Comment: Ok, I have explained it wrong, sorry. The content should still be visible, but outside of the container (fixed centered by css). 

See: https://jsfiddle.net/6dv41792/

Comment: @jpc do you mean you want it to act something like a pop up? the parent div will have its original height but the content will be fixed positioned and centered?

Comment: Yes, exactly this I want to achieve!

Comment: @JPC Sorry for the delayed reply. You can try the new code I have added. This will dynamically collect the parent div height and only affect its parent div. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @jpc glad to hear that. You can accept this answer as solution, so that future user can find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container 
 {
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #EFEFEF;
 padding: 10px; 
}

.content {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #AAA
}
```

try something like this...

Comment: set `height` for `.container` class

Comment: This is, what I can't do, if you read my original post. I have several containers with content in different heights!